# TFS Branch Folder Structure only

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I need to create a branch in TFS from "Main" to "Development-1". However, I only want to branch the folder structure from "Main" and not its file contents.

How can this be done from Team Explorer in TFS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Branching will create the folder structure and file contents at the same time. However, you can remove the folder contents after you have created the branch. This has the advantage of your activity being tracked in history.

Comment: Is there any way to just copy the folder structure? Since removing the folder contents will involve deleting recursively from all folders.